# Where is network directory mounted (direct path)?

Tags: networking, mount, paths, sftp, mountpoint

I connected to a server using `sftp` from within Ubuntu's file manager (**Files**, is it?). Now I'd like to know where it is actually mounted within the Linux file system (i.e. a mount point like `/mnt/network/192.168.1.1/folder`). I used `mount` to list all mounted directories but the network directory doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found it. It's:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp\:host\=192.168.1.1
```

Could someone still explain a little bit more why it is mounted there?